# Multiple inheritance in Python; how to do so in Java?

Tags: java, python, multiple-inheritance

I'm porting some Python code to Java, and I am having trouble dealing with the following problem:

I have some classes which need to have abilities A, B, or C. Class 1 needs ability A, class 2 needs A, B and C, and class 3 needs B and C. Most importantly, I want to easily be able to change what class can have what ability in the future.

I solved this problem pretty easily with multiple inheritance in Python. I'm trying to figure out the best way to do it in Java, but I can't come up with as good of a solution. I know multiple inheritance is frowned-upon, so I'd appreciate being taught a better way.

Thanks!

Comment: Once it is working, do you _need_ to have it in Java? Maybe it is possible to run your Python solution on the JVM by use of Jython.

Comment: @jsbueno: Unfortunately, I need it to be in Java because it's for Android. Anyway, it's a learning experience :)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple-inheritance ain't frowned upon.  What is frowned upon is "implementation inheritance" (also known as "code reuse"), because it leads to the unsolvable "diamond problem".  And because, well, code-reuse really hasn't much to do with OO.

What you want to do can be solved using multiple inheritance (and, say, delegation if you need to do "code reuse").

```
interface A {

    void move();

}

interface B {

    void eat();

}

interface C {

    void think();

}

class One implements A { ... }

class Two implements B { ... }

class Three implements B, C { ... }
```

Any OOA/OOD using multiple inheritance can be trivially translated to Java.  The part where you say that you need to change the "ability" all the time is a bit scary: if, say, a `Car` can `move()`, why would it suddenly need to be able to `think()`?

Comment: Definitely satisfies the specs. My issue is that each class will implement A, B, or C in the exact same way as other classes. Thus, I'd like a solution where I only have to define A once. Since A will utilize class variables using `this`, I'm not sure where I can define it outside of all of the classes for this solution. Let me know if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: @awegawef: in Java you need to create a concrete implementation for 'A' once and then you can "wrap" an instance of 'A' in, say, 'One'.  You then "delegate" the calls to the "wrapped subject".  *BUT* you still have to provide a *void move()* inside One.  However, that method needs to be only one line long: the one containing the delegating call.  (btw the terminology I used here [delegate,wrapped subject] is related to the 'Decorator pattern' mentionned in another answer and that isn't a coincidence)

Comment: I'd advise you to define your sources for your terms. Facilitating code reuse is one of the whole points of OOP, so I assume you're using some non-standard definition of code reuse.

Comment: @SpoonBender, I believe I understand. However, my implementation for A will rely on class variables, ie `this.user`, so I don't quite understand where I can implement that. Once I have it implemented, I can of course just point the other One.A() etc calls to the A method.

Comment: The diamond problem has been successfully addressed in many languages. Perhaps you have a non-standard definition of 'unsolvable' too?

Comment: "unsovable diamond problem" is just dogma used by the time of Java specification. If you read how Python implements multiple inheritance you can see it is quite "solvable", just like ost software problems.

Comment: @Visionary Software Solutions: I love your humble nickname ;)   Don't despair: the "code reuse" you think you achieve by using concrete (aka implementation) inheritance in Java can be achieved much more cleanly by using delegation.  One day you'll see the OOP light (but it won't be soon so be patient).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your actual use case, but have you already considered decorators?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've looked into it, but I'm not very attracted to that solution because IMO it has a lot of unnecessary code and makes it harder to modify in the future.

Comment: As opposed to locking yourself into an inheritance hierarchy that may cause breaking changes if you modify the base class in the future? Inheritance is brittle. http://www.pbell.com/index.cfm/2006/10/16/Why-you-should-favor-composition-over-inheritance

Comment: Decorators don't exactly isolate you from changes either. Consider `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`: It takes a `Set` and returns a `Set` whose mutator methods throw exceptions. Which is great (and very useful). But then `Set` has a subinterface `SortedSet`; for that, they needed to add `Collections.unmodifiableSortedSet()`, even though (IIRC) there aren't any new mutator methods in `SortedSet`. Then, in Java 1.6, they added `NavigableSet`, compounding the problem; there's still no `Collections.unmodifiableNavigableSet()`.

Comment: (I should say, multiple inheritance would be in most ways a decidedly *worse* way to define immutable views of collections. The decorator factory is a much nicer solution overall. But in narrowing the interface of the returned value, it loses some potential uses.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use AspectJ's mixin syntax fairly easily to emulate multiple inheritance (and at compile time too).  First, declare an interface for the functionality you want to mixin:

```
public interface A{
    String getSomethingForA();
}
```

then define an annotation which you can use to signify that you want the mixin applied to a given class:

```
public @interface WithA {}
```

then add the annotation to the class you want to use:

```
@WithA
public class MyClass {}
```

then, to actually add some functionality:

```
@Aspect
public class MixinA {
    public static class AImpl implements A{
        public String getSomethingForA() {
            return "it worked!";
        } 
    }

    @DeclareMixin("@WithA *")
    public static A get() {
        return new AImpl();
    }
}
```

You'll need to use the aspectj jars and run the aspects as part of your compile process, but this lets you create truly modularized functionality and then forcibly merge it into your classes later.  To access your class with the new functionality, do the following:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
((A)obj).getSomethingForA();
```

You can apply the same annotation to another class and cast it as well:

```
@WithA
@WithB //let's pretend we created this with some other functionality
public class AnotherClass {}

AnotherClass anotherObj = new AnotherClass();
((A)anotherObj).getSomethingForA();
((B)anotherObj).andSetSomethingElseForB("something else");
```

Comment: it's all nice and shiny but the question wasn't really tagged 'AspectJ' or was it!?  ;)

Comment: There's a reason there's a giant library of third party libs for java, and it's not just because they can be pretty ;)

Comment: Yeah, but what Java question *can't* be answered by liberal application of AspectJ? :-)

Comment: Plus, this is kind of an involved solution for a simple design question. Adding AOP to the mix is like solving drilling a 2 inch hole with a jackhammer.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple inheritance is almost always a bad idea, as its effects can usually be achieved through other mechanisms. Based upon your description of the problem, it sounds like you want to

1. Use interfaces to define behavior (public interface A) in this scenario, each behavior should probably have its own interface.

If 2 behaviors are tightly coupled (say A & B), define an interface that implements those two atomic interfaces (public interface CombinedAandB extends A, B)

1. Define an abstract base class that implements the interface to provide default implementations for behaviors

   ```
   public abstract class BaseAB implements A, B
   {
      @Override 
      public void A() { add(0,1); }


      @Override
      public void B() {add(1,0); }


      private void add(int a, int b) //it doesn't return. no soup for you.
      { a + b; //If you know why this is wrong, high five yourself. }


   }
   ```
2. Define a concrete class that extends the abstract base class, implements another interface, and provides its own behavior.

   public class IDoABAndC extends BaseAB implements C
   {
     //stuff, etc
   }

Comment: Right, but since I can't extend from multiple abstract base classes, I can't have multiple default implementations for the behaviors (using this idea) without placing one of the implementations in a class and then referencing it from the others, which seems undesirable.

Comment: "I can't have multiple default implementations for the behaviors (using this idea) without placing one of the implementations in a class and then referencing it from the others, which seems undesirable" Are you suggesting it is undesirable to reference another class using delegation? No no no, my young padawan. Favor Composition Over Inheritance. http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html  http://books.google.com/books?id=LjJcCnNf92kC&lpg=PP1&dq=head%20first%20design%20patterns&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q=favor%20composition&f=false

Comment: @awegawef It seems you're in an awkward spot — multiple inheritance is unnecessary 99% of the time (which is why Java doesn't have it), but when you need it, it's a PITA not to have it.

Comment: "Class 1 needs ability A, class 2 needs A, B and C, and class 3 needs B and C. Most importantly, I want to easily be able to change what class can have what ability in the future." Upon further reflection, I highly suspect that you're actually trying to use the Strategy Pattern, not Decorator. If you want to be able to quickly "change abilities in the future", read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern Head First Design Patterns Chapter 1 walks through an excellent example of this.

Comment: @luke, haha! @visionary, I understand, thanks for the comment. My frustration is it is much simpler to write `... extends BaseA, BaseB, BaseC`. I know exactly where to go to debug that functionality, and if I want to remove or add other functionality, I can just change how the class extends. I should stop being so lazy :P

EDIT: Ah, @visionary, didn't see that last comment. I'll look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the abilities in interfaces and implement them in your classes.

Answer (score 0):

In java you don't have multiple inheritance, instead you can implement multiple interfaces.

So your class 1 will implement interface A and B. Class 2 will implement interface A, B and C. Class 3 will implement B and C.

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is *interface* inheritance, then as mentioned before, you can always implement multiple interfaces.

If you're looking for *implementation* inheritance, you're somewhat out of luck. The best solution is probably to use delegation — replace the extra superclasses with fields, and implement methods that just delegate to those fields. It does require writing a lot of repetitive delegation methods, but it's rather unavoidable in Java (without resorting to AspectJ or other bytecode-munging tricks; careful, this way madness lies …).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tangential, but you can have python code running in Java via Jython (http://www.jython.org/). This addresses the porting to Java part, not the solving multiple inheritance part (I think you need to determine which is relevant)